# What is the equivalent HttpClient JSON POST to this RestClient JSON POST?

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient

Given:

```
Uri location = ...; // Remote 3rd party HTTP Rest API
string body = "SOME JSON";
```

The following `RestClient` code generates HTTP traffic that is accepted by the server.

```
var client = new RestClient(location);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", body, 
   ParameterType.RequestBody);
var restResponse = client.Execute(request);
```

However, the `HttpClient` code below must be generating different HTTP traffic (indicated by the server rejecting the request).

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
  request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
  request.RequestUri = location;
  var bodyContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  request.Content = bodyContent;
  request.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
  client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0);
  var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Why is the HttpClient code serializing differently?

Comment: Need more details when you say the sever is rejecting it. Status code, body, etc.  do you own the server?  Is it looking for a specific header?  Have you tried spinning up a local api to see how the request is being received?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the upvote. I have restated the question to emphasize I am trying to replicate the behavior RestClient is exhibiting (not necessarily trying to get a working client/server API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to find the precise differences is to run Fiddler or another debugging proxy and check the raw request. Here's what I got with HttpClient:

```
POST http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 4
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

test
```

And with RestSharp:

```
POST http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/106.6.9.0
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

test
```

Your results may differ depending on your system configuration, versions etc., so you should try it yourself to make sure.