# C#: Not able to get child value from JSON string

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm working with .net core. I hit an third-party api call with in a controller. I get response from the call. And ***response.Content*** is something like below.

```
"{\"GetAlertingTransactionsResult\":\"{\\\"Success\\\":true,\\\"Data\\\":[{\\\"RowNum\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"TransactionID\\\":\\\"611\\\",\\\"TransactionType\\\":\\\"Authorization\\\",\\\"Channel\\\":\\\"POS\\\",\\\"TxnStatusDescription\\\":\\\"Processed\\\",\\\"ErrorCode\\\":\\\"0000\\\",\\\"MID\\\":\\\"999222222222222\\\",\\\"TID\\\":\\\"99922236\\\",\\\"MerchantName\\\":\\\"NEW POS TEST MERCHANT\\\",\\\"MerchantAddress\\\":\\\"TEST ADDRESS LINE1 TEST ADDRESS LINE2\\\",\\\"TransactionAmount\\\":\\\"999.9900\\\",\\\"TipAmount\\\":\\\"0.0000\\\",\\\"DiscountAmount\\\":\\\"0.0000\\\",\\\"TotalAmount\\\":\\\"999.9900\\\",\\\"ApplicationVersion\\\":\\\"V6.0.0\\\",\\\"ApplicationID\\\":\\\"A0000007362010\\\",\\\"TxnDateTime\\\":\\\"7\\/9\\/2020 2:36:07 PM\\\",\\\"RequestDateTime\\\":\\\"7\\/9\\/2020 2:36:59 PM\\\",\\\"ResponseDateTime\\\":\\\"7\\/9\\/2020 2:36:59 PM\\\",\\\"InvoiceNumber\\\":\\\"4\\\",\\\"OldInvoiceNumber\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"BatchNumber\\\":\\\"15\\\",\\\"AuthNumber\\\":\\\"123\\\",\\\"AssociationName\\\":\\\"PayPakCard\\\",\\\"TC\\\":\\\"123\\\",\\\"ExpiryDate\\\":\\\"123\\\",\\\"ARQC\\\":\\\"2C254884E80D7FD2\\\",\\\"CardHolderName\\\":\\\"DEBIT\\/PAYPAK              \\\",\\\"MaskedCardNumber\\\":\\\"2205 60** **** 0476\\\",\\\"Cardtype\\\":\\\"CHIP\\\",\\\"TSI\\\":\\\"6800\\\",\\\"TVR\\\":\\\"123\\\",\\\"AppLabel\\\":\\\"PayPak Debit\\\",\\\"TotalTxnCount\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"TerminalSerialNumber\\\":\\\"82683858\\\",\\\"CompositeKey\\\":\\\"123\\\",\\\"PINCaptureCode\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"IsReprint\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"CustomerMobileNo\\\":null,\\\"IPAddress\\\":\\\"43.245.8.61\\\",\\\"RRN\\\":\\\"123\\\"}],\\\"TotalNumberOfRecords\\\":1}\"}"
```

Now I want to get values of e.g TransactionID, TransactionType and Channel etc.
**How would I be able to get these values in C# (.net Core)?**

For reference: Code of How I'm calling a third party API.

```
var client = new RestClient("third-party-api-link-here");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("application/json",
            "{\r\n\"TransactionReportDTO\":\r\n{\r\n\"PageSize\":\"15\",\r\n\"PageIndex\":\"1\",\r\n\"TransactionType\":\"Authorization\",\r\n\"Channel\": \"POS\",\r\n\"MerchantName\" :\"NEW POS TEST MERCHANT\",\r\n\"TransactionAmount\" :999.9900,\r\n\"TotalAmount\":999.9900,\r\n\"MID\" :\"999222222222222\",\r\n\"TID\": \"99922236\",\r\n\"InvoiceNumber\":\"4\",\r\n\"RRN\": \"202007091436\",\r\n\"CardNumber\":\"2205600050000476\",\r\n\"TransactionStartDate\":\"2020-07-09\",\r\n\"TransactionEndDate\":\"2020-07-09\"\r\n}\r\n\r\n}"
           , ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469046/what-is-the-equivalent-httpclient-json-post-to-this-restclient-json-post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: No it doesn't work for me. Do you have anyother suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the response using `JObject` and `JArray`. You need to include `Newtonsoft.Json` package in project.

```cs
var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseString)["GetAlertingTransactionsResult"];
var jDataObject = JObject.Parse(jObject.ToString());
var objectArray = JArray.Parse(jDataObject["Data"].ToString());
Console.WriteLine(objectArray[0]["TransactionID"].ToString());
```

See code -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/wSjJYr

Optionally you can create concrete class and do.

```cs
public class Root    
{
    public string GetAlertingTransactionsResult { get; set; } 
    private SubRoot _getTransactionsResult;
    public SubRoot TransactionsResult { get =>  _getTransactionsResult ??= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubRoot>(GetAlertingTransactionsResult); } 
}

public class SubRoot 
{
    public bool Success { get; set; } 
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; } 
    public int TotalNumberOfRecords { get; set; } 
}

public class Datum    
{
    public string TransactionID { get; set; } 
}

var rObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseString);  
var tId = rObject.TransactionsResult.Data.First().TransactionID);
```

See code -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/tU5NI0

Comment: Thankyou! The above method worked for me. Now I am able to get values of each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party package like Newtonsoft.Json and add it to project references by:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

or dotnet cli :

```
dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json
```

finally use the JsonConvert class and get the value:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
```

Comment: Sir It's giving null values

Comment: What exactly give you the null value?
DeserializeObject is a generic function which try to Deserialize your json content to a c# model(with public props), if it returns null, it couldn't deserialize your content.

Comment: I don't have any class/model as like you have mentioned "Movie". I just want to extract values of TransactionId, and TransactionType and store it into a third variable. That's all what I want to do.

Comment: The above code is only an example, it's not your complete solution, you should create a class for your model(TransactionModel) and create public properties just like the result, for example : 
public int TransactionId {get; set;} 
public int TransactionType {get; set;} 

then try to deserialize response to the model:
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionModel>(json);

Comment: I have created a class with some properties like 
public string TransactionType {get; set;} and so on and run the following but it still gives null value on m.TransactionType


**TransactionReportDTO m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionReportDTO>(fakeResponse);

            string TransactionType  = m.TransactionType;**

Answer (score 0):

lets say you know all about api calls and getting string response.

for example you have got this response body from your call.

```
var responseBody="{
                   "userId": 1,
                   "id": 1,
                   "title": "delectus aut autem",
                   "someArray": [{"someId":3}]
                  }"
```

we want to fetch the object who has "someId"=3 !
we can approach the answer with multipe ways, first you can create a class with the same logic as our response body and then Convert our json string to an object of a class using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert, the next way is to create a JObject class and move within the response .
for the second way the example is like bellow:

```
var responseObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject> 
                   (responseBody)
var o = (responseObject["someArray"] as JArray).FirstOrDefault(o=>Convert.ToInt16(o["someId"].toString()) == 3)
```

now o is an object from class JObject. this way you dont need to declare a class for your responseBody , but from clean code view is not the best practice

Answer (score 0):

you can use online tools such as https://json2csharp.com to convert your json object to C# class and create data model out of it , then use `Newtonsoft.Json` to Deserialize json into c# object

Answer (score 0):

There are no TransctionID .But transction type is there

```js
 string str = "{\r\n\"TransactionReportDTO\":\r\n{\r\n\"PageSize\":\"15\",\r\n\"PageIndex\":\"1\",\r\n\"TransactionType\":\"Authorization\",\r\n\"Channel\": \"POS\",\r\n\"MerchantName\" :\"NEW POS TEST MERCHANT\",\r\n\"TransactionAmount\" :999.9900,\r\n\"TotalAmount\":999.9900,\r\n\"MID\" :\"999222222222222\",\r\n\"TID\": \"99922236\",\r\n\"InvoiceNumber\":\"4\",\r\n\"RRN\": \"202007091436\",\r\n\"CardNumber\":\"2205600050000476\",\r\n\"TransactionStartDate\":\"2020-07-09\",\r\n\"TransactionEndDate\":\"2020-07-09\"\r\n}\r\n\r\n}";
            var jObject = JObject.Parse(str);

            string ttype = (string)jObject["TransactionReportDTO"]["TransactionType"];
```